# Why are no OCR engines working in Gscan2pdf after upgrading to 14.04?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, ocr

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, but the OCR in gscan2pdf stopped working.  I am using the latest gscan2pdf (1.2.4) with both Tesseract and Cuneiform available.

When loading pdf documents in gscan2pdf, both OCR engines are available and they look like they are working, but no output.  I tried using various older versions of gscan2pdf to no avail.  It was working fine with 13.10.  This function is very important for my work.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple patch fix for this which can be found at: http://sourceforge.net/p/gscan2pdf/bugs/173/

Answer (score 0):

ok yesterady gscan2pdf 1.2.5 was published. Now it works fine again with tesseract-ocr 3.03.02-3 (standard package from Trusty) and gscan2pdf 1.2.5 (from ppa:jeffreyratcliffe/ppa).